# replace dashes in to space using php

Tags: php, regex

can you help me in my problem.

i want to create a function to replace the space into dash then i found a solution for that

**this is the sulotion i found:**

```
function slug($phrase, $maxLength=100000000000000)
    {
        $result = strtolower($phrase);

        $result = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\s-._\/]/", "", $result);
        $result = trim(preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $result));
        $result = trim(substr($result, 0, $maxLength));
        $result = preg_replace("/\s/", "-", $result);

        return $result;
    }
```

my problem is i want to create a vice versa for that replace dash to space

**example input:**

dash-to-space

**example output**

dash to space

how can i do that?

Comment: Provide some examples of input/output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based `preg_replace`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<!\s)-(?!\s)/', ' ', $input);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xP1nZ5/1)

This will avoid replacing `-` by space if it is surrounded by space.

Answer (score 3):

the first lines are only cleaning up the string.

The last line performs the replace function.

switching the parameters around should do the trick

`$result = preg_replace("/\-/", " ", $result);`

Comment: Yes, that would also work in his initial code but that is not what he is using. That is why I stayed with his code.

Answer (score 2):

**It will help you :**

```
$output = str_replace(',', ' ', $result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$result = str_replace('-', ' ', $result);` => - to spaces

`$result = str_replace(' ', '-', $result);` => spaces to -